# How to remove gridline in ListView when upper and lower item have the same background color

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

On the left is what's happening.  On the right is what I want to happen.

[image: Example screenshot]

I want to remove the grid-lines in the `ListView` in cases like that.  Is it possible?  I'm setting the back-colors in code.

Comment: I assume this is a WinForm project?

Comment: Ok, I added the tag for that.  In the future, when asking UI specific questions, it's best to specify and tag the technology (e.g. WinForm, ASP.NET, WPF).

Comment: Gridlines are implemented as part of an internal extended style.  You'd have to turn them off and draw them all yourself.  It would be complicated because of scrolling and because you would no longer be drawing gridlines but line segments